# Distinguish efficiently between different possible combinations in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a two-element tuple `t`, each element is either a positive integer or `None`, and the combination may be in one of the four forms:

1: `(x, y)`: e.g. (2, 3)

2: `(x, x)`: e.g. (1, 1)

3: `(x, None)` (or equivalently, `(None, x)`) : e.g. (3, None) or (None, 5)

4: `(None, None)`

My application logic wants to treat 2) and 3) as one case, 1) as the second case, and 4) as the third case.

I want to find an operation on a given tuple to make it easier/more efficient to distinguish between the three cases. For example, `t[0] or t[1]` will help us distinguish between the case of 2) and 3) and that of 4), but it cannot distinguish 2) and 3) from 1).

In the end, I want to minimize the number of `if` checks needed.

Comment: Do you have to distinguish between `0` and `None`?

Comment: @orlp, 0 is not a possible value, because "*each element is either a positive integer or `None`*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
if t[0] or t[1]:
    if t[0] == t[1] or not (t[0] and t[1]):
        # 2-3rd case
    else:
        # 1st case
else:
    # 4th case
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible do it without if statements, like this horror code do:

```
def check(t):
  [
    lambda x: print(x, "match case 4"),
    None,
    lambda x: print(x, "match case 2 or 3"),
    lambda x: print(x, "match case 1")
  ][sum((bool(t[0]), bool(t[1]), t[0] != t[1]))](t)
```

the key of solution is `sum((bool(t[0]), bool(t[1]), t[0] != t[1]))`, this works because,
`(x, y)` pass in all checks,
`(x, x)` pass in two checks (`bool(t[0])` and `bool(t[1])`),
`(None, x)` pass in two too (`bool(t[1])` and `t[0] != t[1]`) and
`(None, None)` pass in no one